# BigQuery:Transfer WildCard Table from One Account to another

Tags: google-bigquery

We are moving our BigQuery data from QA to production environment.
For that we have created new google account for production environment.

How we can transfer wildcard  table data from one google account to another ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use google groups to very fast copy tables between projects/datasets for different google accounts.

1. Set up a google group from the main google account
2. Invite the new google account (as owner) to the google group
3. Accept the invitation from the new google accounts gmail.
4. Share the original data set using the shared google group email. Under dataset name select the arrow down & pick Share dataset. Make sure to share as group and not user and make the account an owner (or you can not copy tables)
5. From the new google account create a new project & dataset in BQ. Then add the old project id to the new google account under Switch to project/ Display project  (under the arrrow down under the dataset name). You can now see the old project/dataset and all its tables from the new google account. From there you can copy any tables from the old project to the new project/google account. Very large tables within seconds.

Edit: I think you need to use old UI for this to work since the options does not seem to be available in the new one yet

Comment: Yes , I have previously done this for all the tables and view, but I have couple of wild card table for which new tables is created for each date. I am looking solution for that one. it is not feasible to copy tables which is created for each day.(180 tables for 6 months data)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the BigQuery data from your source account/project by using the logic of exporting the BigQuery dataset to a GCS bucket and then importing the data to the new BigQuery dataset located in your destination account/project.

> 1. [Export the data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) from your source BigQuery account/project to a regional or multi-region Cloud Storage bucket in the same location
>      as your dataset.
> 2. [Grant the required GCS and BigQuery permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage#required_permissions) to the account that will be used to load the data in the destination
>      account/project by using the [IAM console](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#using_iam_with_buckets).
> 3. [Load your data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage#next_steps) into your destination BigQuery account/project based on the data format selected during the export task.

There are no charges for exporting data from BigQuery to Cloud Storage and vice versa; Nevertheless, you do incur charges for storing the data. I suggest you to take a look on the [Free Operations when using BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free) to know more about this.